# C - When I read from a file, it reads from a pipe instead

Tags: c, file, pipe

I am new to C and I am doing a Uni project that I will explain here:

I have got 2 files, pfc.c and transdurcers.c and there are 3 processes, one is transudcers, the other two are both are pfc

I have to make pfc communicate with transudercs in 2 different ways:

One from writing in a file (pfc3) and making transducers read from it.

One from using a pipe (pfc2).

So one process write with file and the other one write with a pipe, transducers has to read em both at the same time
In both case I only have to send the value of a variable char speed[10] **every second**;
So I also have two whiles that make everything write and read every second.

But there is a big problem, the value I read from the file, is not the one in the file, but the one in the pipe, I have debugged all my code and I am 100% sure about this.
I don't know how it is possible, what am I missing?
Thank you for your help, here is my code:

This is how I create the pipe and file in **pfc**

```
void pfc2()
{
    createPipe();
    readCoordinates();
    
    if(pipeFd != -1)
    {
        write(pipeFd,f_end,sizeof(f_end));
        
        close(pipeFd);
        
        unlink("../tmp/PipePFC2");
    }
}

void pfc3()
{
    createFile();
    readCoordinates();
    
    FILE * fileTransudcers = fopen("../tmp/PFC3Transducers.txt", "w");
        
    if(fileTransudcers != NULL)
    {
        fputs(f_end,fileTransudcers);
    }
    
    fclose(fileTransudcers);
}

void createFile()
{
    FILE * fileTransudcers = fopen("../tmp/PFC3Transducers.txt", "w");
    
    if(fileTransudcers != NULL)
    {
        fclose(fileTransudcers);
    }
}

void createPipe()
{
    unlink("../tmp/PipePFC2");
    mkfifo("../tmp/PipePFC2",0666);
    pipeFd = open("../tmp/PipePFC2",O_WRONLY);
}
```

This is how I write in **pfc**

```
void writePFC3()
{
    FILE * fileTransudcers = fopen("../tmp/PFC3Transducers.txt", "w");
    int fd_fpTransducers = fileno(fileTransudcers);
    
    if(fileTransudcers != NULL)
    {
        fputs(speed,fileTransudcers);
        printf("SpeedPFC3: %s\n",speed);
    }
    
    if(fileTransudcers != NULL)
    {
        fclose(fileTransudcers);
    }
}

void writePFC2()
{
    if(pipeFd != -1)
    {
        write(pipeFd,speed,sizeof(speed));
        printf("SpeedPFC2: %s\n",speed);
    }
}
```

This is how I open the file and pipe in **transducers**

```
void openTransducerFile()
{
    do
    {
        fileTransducers = fopen("../tmp/PFC3Transducers.txt", "r");
    } while (fileTransducers == NULL);
}

void openPipe()
{
    do
    {   
        pipeFd = open("../tmp/PipePFC2",O_RDONLY);
    }
    while(pipeFd == -1);
}
```

This is how I read from the file and pipe in **transducers**

```
void readSpeedPFC2()
{
    if(pipeFd != -1)
    {
        char line2[10];
    
        read(pipeFd,line2,10);
    
        speedPFC2 = line2;
    }
    else    
    {
        printf("Impossibile ricevere PFC2.");
    }
}

void readSpeedPFC3()
{
    if(fileTransducers != NULL)
    {
        char line3[10];
    
        fgets(line3,10,fileTransducers);
        
        speedPFC3 = line3;
    }
    else    
    {
        printf("Impossibile ricevere PFC3.");
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think you should include your full code. In particular, I'm wondering if you are trying to read `speedPFC3` after calling `readSpeedPFC3`. You probably need to use `strcpy`/`memcpy` instead of `speedPFC3 = line3`

Comment: You cannot be "100% sure" about anything since you didn't check the value returned by read.

Comment: @KrenarHoxha Do you know about local variables? What is the lifetime of a local variable? When does it get created, and when does it get destroyed? What happens if you use a pointer which pointed to a variable that was destroyed?

Comment: @EdmCoff I didn't include it because I think it would be usless since there are other things external to this problem. But if it could help I can post it. I will also try strcpy and look if it works

Comment: @WilliamPursell Obviously I have not posted all the various printf that I have done, but I can guarantee you that I have tried to print everywhere and I know with certainty that fgets does not read from files but from the pipe.
This is because I tried to make them both write different values ​​and the only read is that of the pipe.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the pipe is working well, I don't need to check the `read`, the problem is that fgets reads from the pipe

Comment: You cannot do this: `{char array[10]; /*some code*/; pointer = array;}`  When the code gets to the closing brace the array doesn't exist any more.  You think it does because the memory still contains something - but it is just luck that it is something you think is valid data.  If you want to have access to the array's after the closing brace you need to  copy the data somewhere else before the closing brace - probably using strcpy or memcpy (depending if the data is NUL terminated)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I have `char line3[10];` where I put what I read from the file and `char * speedPFC3` which is a global variable and then I do `speedPFC3=line3`. I don't need none of them before calling `readSpeedPFC3()` again, because I already used em at that moment, and I don't know what you mean because there's no problem with that. Actually it doesn't work when I use `strcpy`.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah the problem is this one: if I print line2 and line3, they are the same, how could it be possible? I debugged trying to write different things in the pipe and the file, and they are actually different. I opened the file and the things are different there from how they are in line3. Guys, I don't know how can I tell u this, but my fgets from the file reads from the pipe, it really is like that.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I am 100% sure that they write different things in file and pipe. I debugged it all day. And the problem isn't `speedPFC3=line3`, the problem is that `read(pipeFd,line2,10);` and `fgets(line3,10,fileTransducers);` read the same value from the pipe, fgets dont read from `fileTransducers`